# Textbox cursor landing in the middle instead of beginning of line

Tags: html, textarea, styling

I am making a page where I try to allow people to write about parks they know about.  A problem I am having is that when a person tries to edit a park, the cursor in the text area ends up what seems to be 1 tab over from the beginning.

Here is an example:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=447

On the left column, if click on "Write and share what you know about this topic" you will see that the cursor doesn't end up in the beginning of the text area.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's obviously data (looks like 2 tabs) being output in the value of the textbox, or is stored in the database with the existing data.

Ah yes, it's between your textarea tags.  Remove the tabs.

Comment: That fixed the tab issue thank you. But now there is no cursor at all unless I click on the textarea - can the cursor be placed at the beginning of the text area? Thanks!

Comment: @Genadinik Why would there be?..  You can focus the control with javascript if you like.

Comment: Yeah I think that would be good for that page.  Is there a simple way to place the cursor at the beginning of that line in JS?  Thank you!

Comment: @Genadinik Give the textarea an ID attribute, like `<textarea id="commentBox"></textarea>` and then add a script that says `document.getElementById('commentBox').focus();`

Comment: @Genadinik I see you have a name attribute already.. you could use getElementByName() instead, but I prefer ID's in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

get rid of the space between the textarea tags and that will solve that problem:

```
<textarea>     </textarea>
```

```
<textarea></textarea>
```